# ine 0, col 19: Error: Expected known function, got 'MONTH'

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Got "Line 0, col 19: Error: Expected known function, got 'MONTH'" error from Doctrine for the following query:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("SELECT tp.id as id,MONTH(tp.dia) as mes,tp.tema as tema, tp.dia as dia, tu.nome as turma FROM AppBundle:TempoProfessor tp, AppBundle:Horario h, AppBundle:Turma tu WHERE tp.horario = h.id AND tu.id = h.turma AND tu.anoLectivo =:ano AND h.professor=:professor GROUP BY mes")
    ->setParameter('professor', $professor)
    ->setParameter('ano', $ano)
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: thanks wprks for me.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine queries are **not** SQL, but [DQL](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) queries. Hence you can't use something that is not part of DQL syntax unless you'll create handler for your syntax extension.

You can use `month()` function if you'll create own function to DQL. Please refer [this part](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language) of documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Oro Doctrine Extensions that include a lot of very uselful functions for DQL:

https://github.com/oroinc/doctrine-extensions